# How do you use the ternary operator in conjunction with echo/what's wrong with mine?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP statement:

```
echo "<p><strong>Ratio:</strong> " . ($row2["losses"] == 0) ? "&infin;</p>" : number_format(($row1["wins"] / $row2["losses"]), 2) . "</p>";
```

What am I doing wrong? It errors every time.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I'd probably write a function rather than use the ternary operator.  It's ugly in this situation, even if you can actually make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<p><strong>Ratio:</strong> " .( ($row2["losses"] == 0) ? "&infin;</p>" : number_format(($row1["wins"] / $row2["losses"]), 2) ). "</p>";
```

You need to put your ternary between ( and ).

Other example (better readable):

```
echo "hi i am ".( $user == "john"? "John" : "Bla")." Doe";
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Comment: @austinBrunkhorst I changed my answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is being interpreted as

```
echo ( "<p><strong>Ratio:</strong> " . ($row2["losses"] == 0) ) ? 
       "&infin;</p>" : 
       number_format(($row1["wins"] / $row2["losses"]), 2) . "</p>";
```

That's because `.` has higher prececence than `?` http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

You need to tell the parser that where the ternary starts and stops, or better yet, split it into more statements so there's no confusion.

```
echo "<p><strong>Ratio:</strong> ";
echo $row2["losses"] == 0 ? "&infin;" : number_format(($row1["wins"] /$row2["losses"]), 2);
echo "</p>";
```